# laravel: is it possible to make a migration from DB to the code?

Tags: laravel-9

I'd like to make some changes on the database side (PHPMyAdmin) since the GUI is user-friendly. Now, I can't figure out how to update my code model with the actual DB structure. Picture for better understanding:
[image]

I use Laravel version 9 and a thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator` package](https://github.com/kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator) which generates migrations for all or some tables:

```sh
php artisan migrate:generate
```

or

```sh
php artisan migrate:generate --tables="table1,table2"
```

Comment: have you used it before? I'll try it out and let you know how it went